# How to determine smallest $M>0$ such that $(Au,v)≤M\Vert u \Vert \Vert v \Vert?$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ provided with the euclidean inner product and norm. Given a linear, bounded and strong positive operator
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 3
\end{bmatrix} 
$$ is it true that the greatest $\mu>0 $ such that $$(Au,u) ≥ \mu\Vert u\Vert^2$$ is the greatest eigenvalue of A as I assume? 
Furthermore, how can I determine the smallest $M>0$ such that $$(Au,v)≤M\Vert u \Vert \Vert v \Vert?$$
I have the assumption to somehow involve the symmetric part $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ to show is as I have seen something similar before. Some help or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you're looking for is not the largest *eigenvalue*; it's the largest *singular value*.

Comment: Can you clarify what "strong positive" means in the context?

Comment: Thanks, so I need to do a singular value decomposition? And why is it so?

Sorry, I mean positive definite by strong positive.

Comment: @Tesla you won't need a full singular value decomposition.  The largest singular value is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Comment: @Tesla also, I misspoke.  Your $M$ is the largest singular value.  Your $\mu$ is something called the [numerical radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range).

Comment: @Tesla for an example where neither $\mu$ nor $M$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, consider the positive definite matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$

Comment: Call $B=(A+A^T)/2$. Then $(Au,u)=(Bu,u)$. Let $S^TS=B$. Then $(Bu,u)=(Su,Su)=\|Su\|^2\geq\|S^{-1}\|^{-2}\|u\|^2$. Since $\|S^{-1}\|$ is the smallest $r$ such that $\|S^{-1}u\|\leq r\|u\|$, therefore $\|S^{-1}\|^{-2}$ is the largest $\mu$ such that $(Au,u)=\|Su\|^2\geq \mu\|u\|^2$.

Comment: @Tesla once again, made a bit of a mistake.  The numerical radius is for considering matrices over $\Bbb C^n$.  When we're considering matrices over $\Bbb R^n$, arugula's trick will suffice.  Ultimately, we can find your $\mu$ by considering only the eigenvalues of $(A + A^T)/2$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom true, just forgot how to compute the singular values for a moment. But is it really the largest and not the smallest singular value and is there a simple argument why it has to be smallest/largest singular value? I am lacking the intuition for it

Comment: @Tesla Yeah, I'll put that in an answer

Comment: @arugula thank you. But isn't $(Bu,u)=\frac{1}{2}(u^TAu + u^T A^T u)$? Why does that equal $(Au,u)$ when $A$ is not symmetric? Or did I miscalculate somewhere

Comment: @Tesla note that
$$
u^T(Au) = (Au)^Tu = u^TA^Tu
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah thanks, missed the point that $u^T(Au)=(u^T(Au))^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments below the answer, the $\mu$ in question will be the smallest eigenvalue of $B = (A + A^T)/2$.  One explanation is as follows:

- For all $u$, we have $(Au,u) = (Bu,u)$
- By the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem (described briefly in the opening blurb [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Matrices)), the minimum value of $(Bu,u)/\|u\|^2$ is the lowest eigenvalue of $B$.

As for $M$: we begin by noting that the largest singular value of $A$ can be described as
$$
\sigma_1(A) = \|A\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\|
$$
With that and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we note that
$$
(Au,v) \leq \|Au\| \cdot \|v\| \leq \sigma_1(A)\cdot \|u\| \cdot \|v\|
$$
To see that this upper bound is attained (i.e. that there exist $u,v$ such that $(Au,v) = \sigma_1(A)\|u\| \|v\|$), it suffices to take a $u$ such that $\|Au\| = \sigma_1(A)$ and take $v = Au$.